# Clearing cache from DOM using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I have data-table with id **depots** in my template. I have created a **modal** in that template which is shown when a specific **href tag** is clicked. Sample code which is responsible for showing modal is below -

```
$("#depots").on("click", ".depots-pricing-details", function (e) {
        .......
});
```

There are several events are binded within this **click** event. My problem is, when the modal is closed and the same modal is opened for another item (at another row), every item of the modal seems displaced.

To escape this problem, i have added **page reloading** functionality in case of modal closing which reloads the page and thus cache is cleared for previous event.

It is not an effective way to overcome the problem. My question is, **is there any jquery method for clearing cache just after closing of any/specific event ?**

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)  which will make us understand the issue?

Comment: Ok. I am trying. But it will take some time. @RayonDabre

Comment: what do you mean by displaced?

Comment: There are several tables in the modal. I was showing only 1/2 at the initial stage. And rest of them are shown based on click events. But after closing the modal, when i opened it again "All of the tables" are showing. Some buttons are missing which are shown in the first modal show event.

Comment: Fiddle is not working..Test it before sharing!

Comment: for these scenario you can use Jquery template and on click events bing jquery template with data and implement modal open method to append the html markup in dialog.

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

could help

Comment: I have used document.location.reload(true). This is reloading my page after closing my modal every time. I am searching for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can clear the contents by using this : $("#id").html(" ");